# Oracle Query for missing hours data

Tags: sql, oracle, date, missing-data, hour

I have a table where there is no data for few hours say (00,01,02,03) , but have data for rest hours .
Please help with the query below how can I modify to get the data for all hours till the current hour irrespective of the data .Below is the query used

```
with t1 as(
SELECT
case when type = 'ABC' then sum(CNT) end START,
case when type = 'CDE' then sum(CNT) end END,
(to_char(date,'hh24')) HOUR, type activity
from XYZ
where date >= trunc(sysdate)
group by 
to_char(date,'hh24'),type)
select distinct hour,
sum(nvl(START,0)) over (order by hour) START,
sum(nvl(END,0)) over (order by hour) END from t1
order by 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should phrase this query as:

```
select sum(case when type = 'ABC' then CNT else 0 end) as START,
       sum(case when type = 'CDE' then CNT else 0 end) as END,
       to_char(date, 'hh24') as HOUR
from XYZ
where date >= trunc(sysdate)
group by to_char(date, 'hh24');
```

Then, if you want missing hours, you need a source of hours.  You can generate one using an explicit query:

```
with hh as (
      select '00' as hh from dual union all
      select '01' as hh from dual union all
      . . .
      select '23' as hh from dual 
     )
select sum(case when xyz.type = 'ABC' then xyz.CNT else 0 end) as START,
       sum(case when xyz.type = 'CDE' then xyz.CNT else 0 end) as END,
       hh.hh
from hh left join
     xyz
     on to_char(xyz.date, 'hh24') = hh.hh and
        xyz.date >= trunc(sysdate)
group by hh.hh
order by hh.hh
```

Note:  There are many other ways to generate the hours -- how they are generated is not particularly important (for instance, you might have a numbers table hanging around that could be used).  The key part of the logic is the `left join` and the conditional aggregation.